# Two-good economy, can we tell if the demand of good 1 rises or falls when the price of good 2 rises (price of 1 is constant)?

Tags: microeconomics, price

Suppose we have a two-good economy, and we know that good 1 is a normal good. Can we then make any meaningful observation about the demand for good 1 when we change the price of good 2 and keep the price of good 1 constant?

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the demand functions](http://njsanders.people.wm.edu/100A/Deriving_Demand_Functions_Examples.pdf) for three cases:

1. CES Utility
2. Leontief Utility
3. Cobb-Douglas Utility

You should be able to see that the first case gives you that demand for good 1 increases, the second case demand for good 1 decreases, and in case 3 it is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If consumers make choices on a constrained budget, the marginal net utility derived from the consumption of the good 1 would be relatively higher than the good 2 after its price hike.

Thus, an indirect effect of the increase of the price of the good 2 would be an increase of the demand for good 1 as consummer preferences realign toward it.

Comment: What if the goods are perfect complements that must be consumed in the ratio 1:1? Your reasoning would then imply that consumption of both 1 and 2 would increase, which is impossible if income is fixed and the budget constraint binds.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't a point worth making, but are we assuming there is no saving/inter-temporal trading within this model (it is after all, explicitly a micro question)?

Comment: @Ubiquitous: it is specified in the question that good 1 is a normal good, not a complement. If it was the case, the consumption of both goods would decrease as the price of good 2 goes up.

Comment: @CodingDahu a good can be both normal and a complement. Normal just means that demand is increasing in income.